# Sorting records by week help please?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have records of employees tagged as 'late' and I want to be able to sort them every week at a given year. I have a dropdown box where the values are from 52 (the last week of 2014) and again values from 1-53 (for the year of 2015). While I am getting my values from week 52 (below I will show you my query),

```
    sqlSelectRecord1 ="SELECT * FROM maintable where tagged_as = 'Late' and WEEKOFYEAR('2014-12-22')";
    psSelectRecord=conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelectRecord1);
    rsSelectRecord1=psSelectRecord.executeQuery();
```

I can't seem to make my way through if there's a way that I can get the records from week 1-53 (year 2015) without making 52 other queries and 52 other resultsets by changing the week of year function. I am stuck! Help please?

As per request by Uriil:

Sample input would be:
Timestamp: Current Date
Encorder: Jane
Tagged As: Late
Time Logged in: 9:05

Output would be:

```
TIME STAMP    ENCODER     NAME    TAGGED AS    TIME LOG IN
12-23-2014    TINE        JANE     LATE         9:30AM
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample input, and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The yearweek function returns values between 1-53 with the proper mode:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2015-1-1', 3) from dual
SELECT YEARWEEK('2015-12-31', 3) from dual
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek